# Trying to setup Xdebugger on docker-compose #using (visual studio code) IDE

Tags: php, docker, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use xdebugger on docker container with vscode IDE. I had follow online tutorial but the xdebugger jus no working. Can anyone help me with this ?
I pressed F5 and refresh browser start to debug and nothing happend...

My file :

### docker-compose.yml

```
 php-apache-environment:
    container_name: php-apache
    build:
        context: ./
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
        - db
    volumes:
        - ./:/var/www/html/
    ports:
        - 8000:80
```

### Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.0-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
RUN pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
&& echo "\n\
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal \n\
xdebug.default_enable = 1 \n\
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1 \n\
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0 \n\
xdebug.remote_enable = 1 \n\ 
xdebug.remote_handle = "dbgp" \n\
xdebug.remote_port = 9003 \n\
xdebug.remote_log = /var/www/html/xdebug.log \n\
" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/dokcer-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
```

### launch.json

```
{
// Utilisez IntelliSense pour en savoir plus sur les attributs possibles.
// Pointez pour afficher la description des attributs existants.
// Pour plus d'informations, visitez : https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    
    {
        "name": "Listen for XDebug on Docker App",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9003,
        "log": true,
        "pathMappings": {
            "/var/www/html": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    },
]
```

}

Comment: You have `xdebug.remote_anable` in your ini file. It should be `xdebug.remote_enable`.

Comment: @cezaryta I fixed the syntax error and this still not working

Comment: Another thing to check is whether `host.docker.internal` does resolve to IP address of the host.